# C++ C2676 error when using "+" to appened 2 strings

Tags: c++-cli

```
Error   C2676   binary '+': 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

I am getting the C2676 error when trying to append two strings. I have tried everything I can think of, but no luck.

The include and using code is as follows.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stream>  
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

//#include <winnt.h>
//#include <WinUser.h>

using namespace std;
using std::string;
using std::wstring;

namespace CppCLRWinformsProjekt {
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace std;
```

The code that is giving me trouble is.

```
private: System::Void bntSelected_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

    int numSelected = this->checkedListBox1->CheckedItems->Count;

    if (numSelected != 0)
    {
        // Set input focus to the list box.
        //SetFocus(lstReceiver);
        string s = "";
        // If so, loop through all checked items and print results.  
        for (int x = 0; x < numSelected; x++)
        {
         // it appears that the first "+" sign is what is giving me trouble
        s = s + lstReceiver + (x + 1).ToString() + " = " +       this->checkedListBox1->CheckedItems[x]->ToString() + "\n";
        }
        this.lstReceiver.Items.Add(s);
    }
```

Comment: You can use `s.append`. I often opt for using string streams in these situations.

Comment: What is the type of `lstReceiver`? It doesn't look like a `std::string`, `char*`, or `char` type due to the way it's used on the last line of code.

Comment: we need a [mre] but it looks like you're trying to concatenate `std::string` and .net `System::String`, that won't work directly. Changing `string s` to `System::String^ s` will probably work?

Comment: Don't mix string types, fix with `String^ s = "";`

Comment: That worked the simple ones are hardest to find

Comment: lstRecever is a list box